# Facebook Video Embed API allowfullscreen=false doesn't work which makes .play() function throw error

Tags: reactjs, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, fullscreen, video-embedding

I am trying to embed facebook video on my mobile site and used their Video API [documented here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/api) to do it.

I have initialised the video player as described and created Play & Pause buttons to control the video but when I use the Play button I get the error `Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.`

I have tried making `data-allowfullscreen="false"`
but that doesn't seem to work as the iframe that is loaded contains `allowfullscreen="true"`
Look at the image below, my  has it false but the loaded iframe has it as true

[Loaded iframe has allowfullscree=true even though I gave false in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3nYz.png)

I am using React and made a simple component for this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Vidtest extends Component {

    handlePlayVideo = () => {
        window.my_video_player.play(); 
    }

    handlePauseVideo = () => {
        window.my_video_player.pause();
    }   

    render() {
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <div style={{position:"relative", width:"100%"}}>
                    <div id="video_div"
                    className="fb-video" 
                    data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10153231379946729/" 
                    data-width="500" 
                    data-allowFullScreen="false"
                    >
                    </div>
                    <Button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handlePlayVideo}>Play Video</Button>
                    <Button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handlePauseVideo}>Pause Video</Button>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default Vidtest
```

and have initialized FB video player in my index.html

```
<div id="root"></div>
let my_video_player
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '{my-app-id}',
      xfbml      : false,
      version    : 'v7.0'
    });

    // Get Embedded Video Player API Instance

    FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.ready', function(msg) {
      if (msg.type === 'video') {
        my_video_player = msg.instance;
        console.log(msg.id);
        console.log('my_video_player created lfakjd');
      }
    });
  };
</script>

<script 
  async 
  defer 
  crossorigin="anonymous"
  src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk/debug.js#xfbml=1&version=v7.0&appId={my-app-id}&autoLogAppEvents=1">
</script>
```

Can someone please help me resolve the issue here.?

I want to play the video using my_video_player.play() and not allow it to play in fullscreen.

Comment: Is the camel-casing in `data-allowFullScreen` supposed to be some sort of special React syntax, that translates back to the actual attribute name you need to use …? The plugin wants this passed via `data-allowfullscreen`

Comment: @CBroe Sorry this was just 1 of the 1000 random iterations I was trying. I am actually using `data-allowfullscreen` in the code and that is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook definitely seems to be doing something different based on the device type (you can test this by using chrome dev tools - device toolbar - and switching between Mobile (no touch) and Desktop device types. The embedded player looks different between the two versions, and the mobile one seems to call requestfullscreen no matter whether the data-allowfullscreen was on or off. As near as I can tell, the only thing that that data-allowfullscreen seems to influence is on desktop, where there is a fullscreen button on the bottom of the video that shows or hides based on that flag.

Facebook embedded videos has a very frustrating and buggy api. They need to catch up with Youtube and Vimeo players.

Comment: I also just stumbled across this thread on the facebook developer support forums:https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/251226252255836/

Comment: So it would appear that Facebook's official response is this:

"After looking into this with the engineering team, they've confirmed that this isn't something we support on mobile at this time. We'll continue tracking this internally as a feature request, but will close this bug report for now as this is the expected behaviour. Thanks for your understanding."

Ugghh, Facebook. The one video player that is causing the most issues.